# How to make PDF of a specific portion with dompdf in laravel

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I am using dompdf with laravel. Wheni have to make PDF, i write the below code in controller.

```
public function download()
{
    $courseoffers =  Courseoffer::all()->get();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.courses.pdf', compact('courseoffers'))->setPaper('a4','landscape');

    return $pdf->download('courseoffer.pdf');
}
```

Here, `pdf.blade.php` is a specific file. But i don't want to use that. i want a specific portion of blade file to make pdf. How do i achieve it.?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your problem?

Comment: here, when im trying to make pdf, i have a view file of pdf.blade.php. but i dont want to use that view file. lets say i have a view page. when we use print we can print a specific area. like that i want to do the same with dompdf

Comment: Ok, Then you can pass one flag variable to that view file and make the condition for the portion which you want to hide or show. This may work for you :)

Comment: do i have to pass that variable via route.? can i provide a sample syntax of the code.?

Comment: Yes, ```$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);``` you can pass data to load view, same as we pass to the laravel view() function, like you have passed `courseoffers` data to your view

Comment: So from my view, how do I execute `$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);` with a button in that view? So that in my view there is a "PDF" button that when clicked downloads a PDF version of what they're viewing. I understand how the above command passes the data to the view for rendering into a PDF. Just how do I run that PHP code from a button?